# How to change design of default forms of library or list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

Hi i want to change default layout of library or list **New,Edit,Disp** Forms.
i need customize design these forms.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the site in sharepoint designer.

- Open Site in SharePoint Designer
- From left side, select List and libraries and Select which list / library form you want to customize.
- You will see your 3 forms(NewForm, EditForm, DispForm)
- Next you will be able to customize.

Complete step by step details is here: http://www.risetime.com/knowledgecenter/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=6

Comment: And this is for SharePoint 2013: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2012/09/20/how-to-create-custom-forms-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx

Comment: this will definatly work in sharepoint designer 2010 because it have designer view. but i am using sharepoint designer 2013 and it does not have any designer view. how i can do in sharepoint designer 2013?

Comment: Mike's link for SP2013